# Finding out the interfaces/protocols a Clojure Record/Type implements?

Tags: clojure

Is there any way I can dynamically find out which interfaces or protocols a Clojure Record or Type implements?

For example I would like to do:

```
(show-protocols some-record-instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to [following article](http://maurits.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/find-which-protocols-are-implemented-by-a-clojure-datatype/) - it answers to your question